# WebRTC - Xamarin. Trying to set local description fails

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, webrtc

I have compiled the WebRTC source from the google repo and have used the jar in a Android Binding Library project along with the native libraries (.so files) in respective architecture folders. The library compiles without errors.

I have the main Android App and have referenced the binding library's output (.dll). The app also compiles without errors.

1. I am able to add the audio track and the video track and the camera comes up.
2. This is my ISDPObserver implementation

```
public class SDPObserver: Java.Lang.Object, ISDPObserver
{
    public void OnCreateFailure(string error)
    {
        _classContext.ReportError("createSDP error: " + error);
    }
    public void OnCreateSuccess(SessionDescription origSdp)
    {
        if (_localSdp != null)
        {
            _classContext.ReportError("Multiple SDP create.");
            return;
        }
        string sdpDescription = origSdp.Description;
        if (_preferIsac)
        {
            sdpDescription = PreferCodec(sdpDescription, _AUDIO_CODEC_ISAC, true);
        }
        if (_videoCallEnabled)
        {
            sdpDescription = PreferCodec(sdpDescription, _preferredVideoCodec, false);
        }
        SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(origSdp.Type, sdpDescription);
        _localSdp = sdp;
        _executor.Execute(new SDPOnCreateSuccessHandler(sdp));
    }
    // THIS IS WHERE THE FREAKING THING FAILS. SESSION DESCRIPTION IS NULL
    public void OnSetFailure(string error)
    {
        _classContext.ReportError("setSDP error: " + error);
    }
    public void OnSetSuccess()
    {
        _executor.Execute(new SDPOnSetSuccessHandler(_localSdp));
    }
}
public class SDPOnCreateSuccessHandler: Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    private SessionDescription __sdp;
    public SDPOnCreateSuccessHandler(SessionDescription sdp)
    {
        __sdp = sdp;
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        if (_peerConnection != null && !_isError)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Set local SDP from " + __sdp.Type);
                _peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(_sdpObserver, __sdp);
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {}
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {}
        }
    }
}
public class SDPOnSetSuccessHandler: Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    private SessionDescription __localSdp;
    public SDPOnSetSuccessHandler(SessionDescription localSdp)
    {
        __localSdp = localSdp;
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        if (_peerConnection == null || _isError)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (_isInitiator)
        {
            // For offering peer connection we first create offer and set
            // local SDP, then after receiving answer set remote SDP.
            if (_peerConnection.RemoteDescription == null)
            {
                // We've just set our local SDP so time to send it.
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Local SDP set succesfully");
                _events.OnLocalDescription(__localSdp);
            }
            else
            {
                // We've just set remote description, so drain remote
                // and send local ICE candidates.
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Remote SDP set succesfully");
                DrainCandidates();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // For answering peer connection we set remote SDP and then
            // create answer and set local SDP.
            if (_peerConnection.LocalDescription != null)
            {
                // We've just set our local SDP so time to send it, drain
                // remote and send local ICE candidates.
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Local SDP set succesfully");
                _events.OnLocalDescription(__localSdp);
                DrainCandidates();
            }
            else
            {
                // We've just set remote SDP - do nothing for now -
                // answer will be created soon.
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Remote SDP set succesfully");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. The OnCreateSuccess triggers as expected and I am able to update the SessionDescription with the autio codec and the cideo codec values. Next, the Run method **SDPOnCreateSuccessHandler** is executed. This is where it fails to set the local description. The **_peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(_sdpObserver, __sdp)** invokes the .NET generated code which is as follows (sorry about the formatting, it just doesn't budge no matter what I do):

```
static IntPtr id_setLocalDescription_Lorg_webrtc_SdpObserver_Lorg_webrtc_SessionDescription_;
// Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='org.webrtc']/class[@name='PeerConnection']/method[@name='setLocalDescription' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='org.webrtc.SdpObserver'] and parameter[2][@type='org.webrtc.SessionDescription']]"
[Register("setLocalDescription", "(Lorg/webrtc/SdpObserver;Lorg/webrtc/SessionDescription;)V", "GetSetLocalDescription_Lorg_webrtc_SdpObserver_Lorg_webrtc_SessionDescription_Handler")]
public virtual unsafe void SetLocalDescription(global::Org.Webrtc.ISdpObserver p0, global::Org.Webrtc.SessionDescription p1)
{
if (id_setLocalDescription_Lorg_webrtc_SdpObserver_Lorg_webrtc_SessionDescription_ == IntPtr.Zero)
    id_setLocalDescription_Lorg_webrtc_SdpObserver_Lorg_webrtc_SessionDescription_ = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(class_ref, "setLocalDescription", "(Lorg/webrtc/SdpObserver;Lorg/webrtc/SessionDescription;)V");
try
{
    JValue * __args = stackalloc JValue[2];
    __args[0] = new JValue(p0);
    __args[1] = new JValue(p1);
    if (GetType() == ThresholdType)
        JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, id_setLocalDescription_Lorg_webrtc_SdpObserver_Lorg_webrtc_SessionDescription_, __args);
    else
        JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, ThresholdClass, JNIEnv.GetMethodID(ThresholdClass, "setLocalDescription", "(Lorg/webrtc/SdpObserver;Lorg/webrtc/SessionDescription;)V"), __args);
}
finally
{}
}
```

The function evaluates to the "if" condition and fails in the line:

```
JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, id_setLocalDescription_Lorg_webrtc_SdpObserver_Lorg_webrtc_SessionDescription_, __args);
```

4. This is the updated Session Description values:

```
v = 0
o = -5449345243432399727 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s = - t = 0 0
a = group: BUNDLE audio video data
a = msid - semantic: WMS ARDAMS
m = audio 9 UDP / TLS / RTP / SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c = IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a = rtcp: 9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a = ice - ufrag: Jyke
a = ice - pwd: j85eXW9UUZMcqKnQ7ZOErU28
a = ice - options: renomination
a = fingerprint: sha - 256 E8: 3A: 8B: 26: CC: 6D: 9C: 8B: 7F: 48: A0: E7: D0: 81: 3F: B2: 2E: E1: 2E: 9A: 07: 4C: CC: 66: 77: F3: 64: FC: 51: 1C: 9B: 85
a = setup: actpass
a = mid: audio
a = extmap: 1 urn: ietf: params: rtp - hdrext: ssrc - audio - level
a = sendrecv
a = rtcp - mux
a = rtpmap: 111 opus / 48000 / 2
a = rtcp - fb: 111 transport - cc
a = fmtp: 111 minptime = 10;
useinbandfec = 1
a = rtpmap: 103 ISAC / 16000
a = rtpmap: 104 ISAC / 32000
a = rtpmap: 9 G722 / 8000
a = rtpmap: 102 ILBC / 8000
a = rtpmap: 0 PCMU / 8000
a = rtpmap: 8 PCMA / 8000
a = rtpmap: 106 CN / 32000
a = rtpmap: 105 CN / 16000
a = rtpmap: 13 CN / 8000
a = rtpmap: 110 telephone - event / 48000
a = rtpmap: 112 telephone - event / 32000
a = rtpmap: 113 telephone - event / 16000
a = rtpmap: 126 telephone - event / 8000
a = ssrc: 701282247 cname: rwclcMyxn371tKuJ
a = ssrc: 701282247 msid: ARDAMS ARDAMSa0
a = ssrc: 701282247 mslabel: ARDAMS
a = ssrc: 701282247 label: ARDAMSa0
m = video 9 UDP / TLS / RTP / SAVPF 96 98 100 127 125 97 99 101 124
c = IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a = rtcp: 9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a = ice - ufrag: Jyke
a = ice - pwd: j85eXW9UUZMcqKnQ7ZOErU28
a = ice - options: renomination
a = fingerprint: sha - 256 E8: 3A: 8B: 26: CC: 6D: 9C: 8B: 7F: 48: A0: E7: D0: 81: 3F: B2: 2E: E1: 2E: 9A: 07: 4C: CC: 66: 77: F3: 64: FC: 51: 1C: 9B: 85
a = setup: actpass
a = mid: video
a = extmap: 2 urn: ietf: params: rtp - hdrext: toffset
a = extmap: 3 http: //www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a = extmap: 4 urn: 3gpp: video - orientation
a = extmap: 5 http: //www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a = extmap: 6 http: //www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a = sendrecv
a = rtcp - mux
a = rtcp - rsize
a = rtpmap: 96 VP8 / 90000
a = rtcp - fb: 96 ccm fir
a = rtcp - fb: 96 nack
a = rtcp - fb: 96 nack pli
a = rtcp - fb: 96 goog - remb
a = rtcp - fb: 96 transport - cc
a = rtpmap: 98 VP9 / 90000
a = rtcp - fb: 98 ccm fir
a = rtcp - fb: 98 nack
a = rtcp - fb: 98 nack pli
a = rtcp - fb: 98 goog - remb
a = rtcp - fb: 98 transport - cc
a = rtpmap: 100 red / 90000
a = rtpmap: 127 ulpfec / 90000
a = rtpmap: 125 H264 / 90000
a = rtcp - fb: 125 ccm fir
a = rtcp - fb: 125 nack
a = rtcp - fb: 125 nack pli
a = rtcp - fb: 125 goog - remb
a = rtcp - fb: 125 transport - cc
a = fmtp: 125 level - asymmetry - allowed = 1;
packetization - mode = 1;
profile - level - id = 42e01f
a = rtpmap: 97 rtx / 90000
a = fmtp: 97 apt = 96
a = rtpmap: 99 rtx / 90000
a = fmtp: 99 apt = 98a = rtpmap: 101 rtx / 90000
a = fmtp: 101 apt = 100
a = rtpmap: 124 rtx / 90000
a = fmtp: 124 apt = 125
a = ssrc - group: FID 1610329415 966940881
a = ssrc: 1610329415 cname: rwclcMyxn371tKuJ
a = ssrc: 1610329415 msid: ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
a = ssrc: 1610329415 mslabel: ARDAMS
a = ssrc: 1610329415 label: ARDAMSv0
a = ssrc: 966940881 cname: rwclcMyxn371tKuJ
a = ssrc: 966940881 msid: ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
a = ssrc: 966940881 mslabel: ARDAMS
a = ssrc: 966940881 label: ARDAMSv0
m = application 9 UDP / TLS / RTP / SAVPF 109
c = IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b = AS: 30
a = rtcp: 9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a = ice - ufrag: Jyke
a = ice - pwd: j85eXW9UUZMcqKnQ7ZOErU28
a = ice - options: renomination
a = fingerprint: sha - 256 E8: 3A: 8B: 26: CC: 6D: 9C: 8B: 7F: 48: A0: E7: D0: 81: 3F: B2: 2E: E1: 2E: 9A: 07: 4C: CC: 66: 77: F3: 64: FC: 51: 1C: 9B: 85
a = setup: actpass
a = mid: data
a = sendrecv
a = rtcp - mux
a = rtpmap: 109 google - data / 90000
a = ssrc: 3087089883 cname: rwclcMyxn371tKuJ
a = ssrc: 3087089883 msid: ApprtcDemo data ApprtcDemo data
a = ssrc: 3087089883 mslabel: ApprtcDemo data
a = ssrc: 3087089883 label: ApprtcDemo data
```

Can anyone take a look and tell me if there is anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I got it worked out.

Two things:
1. The session description was not formatted properly and the TURN server will reject any improperly formatted information.
2. All communications to the TURN server are supposed to be in a single thread and not parallel threads. The method `NewSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` of the IScheduledExecutorService interface does exactly that. An object of the Interface instantiated in the constructor should be reused to execute IRunnable handlers. This will ensure the app is thread safe and events are handled as they get triggered.

Comment: lyer can you provide code sample how you integrate the Webrtc in xamarin forms application

Comment: Sorry, I worked on this quite some time back and it was not a Xamarin forms application. It was an Xamarin Android Project. The WebRTC library has changed a lot ever since and I have since moved on from Xamarin to native Android